SVG Images not loading properly as strict CSP Policy blocking style execution of SVGs, using mat-icon in Angular 16

Parse the HTML Content
You'll need to parse the HTML content, extract the inline styles, and create CSS classes for them. This can be done using the DOMParser in the browser environment.

Extract Inline Styles and Create CSS Classes
Here’s how you can approach this:
code for same
code for remove style
remove style dynamically




processInlineStyles(html: string): { html: string, styles: string } {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  const elements = doc.body.querySelectorAll('*[style]');

  let styleRules = '';
  let classCounter = 0;

  elements.forEach((element) => {
    classCounter++;
    const style = element.getAttribute('style');
    const className = `custom-class-${classCounter}`;

    // Add the new class to the element
    element.classList.add(className);
    element.removeAttribute('style');

    // Create the CSS rule
    styleRules += `.${className} { ${style} }\n`;
  });

  // Create a <style> element
  const styleElement = doc.createElement('style');
  styleElement.innerHTML = styleRules;

  // Add nonce attribute if it exists on window
  if (window['nonce']) {
    styleElement.setAttribute('nonce', window['nonce']);
  }

  // Append the style element to the <head> of the parsed HTML
  if (doc.head) {
    doc.head.appendChild(styleElement);
  } else {
    // If <head> is not present, create it
    const headElement = doc.createElement('head');
    headElement.appendChild(styleElement);
    doc.documentElement.insertBefore(headElement, doc.body);
  }

  return { html: doc.documentElement.outerHTML, styles: styleRules };
}





processInlineStyles(html: string): { html: string } {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  const elements = doc.body.querySelectorAll('*[style]');

  let styleRules = '';
  let classCounter = 0;

  elements.forEach((element) => {
    classCounter++;
    const style = element.getAttribute('style');
    const className = `custom-class-${classCounter}`;

    // Add the new class to the element
    element.classList.add(className);
    element.removeAttribute('style');

    // Create the CSS rule
    styleRules += `.${className} { ${style} }\n`;
  });

  // Check for existing <style> tag in the <head>
  let styleElement = doc.head.querySelector('style');

  if (!styleElement) {
    // If no <style> tag exists, create one
    styleElement = doc.createElement('style');
    doc.head.appendChild(styleElement);
  }

  // Append the generated styles to the existing <style> tag
  styleElement.innerHTML += `\n${styleRules}`;

  // Add nonce attribute if it exists on window
  if (window['nonce']) {
    styleElement.setAttribute('nonce', window['nonce']);
  }

  // Return the modified HTML as a string
  return { html: doc.documentElement.outerHTML };
}



